# Has my dog eaten fox bait?

Tags: dogs, safety, poison

We live on a 10 acre property surrounded on one side by other small properties and on the other, a large expanse of forested bushland. My small 5 year old Kelpie cross and 7 year old cattle dog cross lab escaped their yard yesterday and returned home 6 hours later. The cattle dog vomited 3 times and it was an unusual colour and consistency.

We are now wondering if consuming bait is a possibility for the dogs?

Answer (score 2):

We can't guarantee the answer is no, since we have no idea what toxins might be in that bait. If there is any chance the answer is yes: ***Vet. Now.***